# SQLContext has no attribute createDataFrame

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am very new to spark. So, my question might seem rudimentary.
I have installed Spark on Ubuntu 16.04. And have configured ipython notebook for using it with pyspark.
I am currently trying out examples from https://github.com/jadianes/spark-py-notebooks/blob/master/nb10-sql-dataframes/nb10-sql-dataframes.ipynb 
When I run the following code

```
interactions_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(row_data)
interactions_df.registerTempTable("interactions")
```

I get the error `SQLContext has no attribute createDataFrame`
I have searched for the problem in google and most them said update to a newer version. But I am currently using spark 2.0.2 with Hadoop 2.7

Initially I  was working on Windows and while running the same code I got `Job aborted due to stage failure`, which was a memory issue. I tried increasing the executor memory and driver memory. But it did not work.

So I changed to Ubuntu. Now I am facing a different problem.
Kindly advice.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you use Spark 2, then you can have access to pyspark sql using the `SparkSession`: `spark.createDataFrame(...)`. Did you instanciate the `SQLContext` before calling attribute `createDataFrame`: `sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)`

Comment: Yes, I wrote `sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)` `csv_data = raw_data.map(lambda l: l.split(","))
row_data = csv_data.map(lambda p: Row(
    duration=int(p[0]), 
    protocol_type=p[1],
    service=p[2],
    flag=p[3],
    src_bytes=int(p[4]),
    dst_bytes=int(p[5])
    )
)`

Comment: Could you print what's contained in your object `sqlContext`